# Why does the $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ action on the group cohomology $H^\bullet(G,\mathbb{R})$ factor through $\mathrm{Out}(G)$?

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I am looking for a reference that proves using the (in)homogeneous bar complex for group cohomology that the $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ action on $H^\bullet(G,\mathbb{R})$ factors through $\mathrm{Out}(G)$. All the proofs I have found so far use a topological or derived functors perspective on group cohomology, which I would like to avoid. (I do not have enough space.)

I know that the group cohomology is the cohomology of the homogeneous bar complex:

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
0 & \ra{} & \mathrm{Map}(G,\mathbb{R})^G & \ra{d^0} & \mathrm{Map}(G^2,\mathbb{R})^G & \ra{d^1} & \mathrm{Map}(G^3,\mathbb{R})^G & \ra{d^2} &...
\end{array}
$$ where \begin{equation}
d^n f(g_0,...,g_{n+1})=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} (-1)^i f(g_0,...,\hat{g_i},...,g_{n+1}).
\end{equation}

Then $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\curvearrowright \mathrm{Map}(G^{n+1},\mathbb{R})^G$ by $\sigma.f(g_0,...,g_n)=f(\sigma^{-1}g_0,...,\sigma^{-1}g_n)$. I understand why this gives an action $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\curvearrowright H^\bullet(G,\mathbb{R})$. Now to prove that this factors through $\mathrm{Out}(G)\curvearrowright H^\bullet(G,\mathbb{R})$ I have to find for every $h\in G$ and $f_1\in \mathrm{Map}(G^{n+1},\mathbb{R})^G$ an element $f_2\in \mathrm{Map}(G^{n},\mathbb{R})^G$ such that $f_1(hg_0h^{-1},...,hg_nh^{-1})-f_1(g_0,...,g_n)=d^{n-1}f_2$. This is the point, where I get stuck. What is $f_2$?

I would be equally happy for a proof using the inhomogeneous bar complex:$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
0 & \ra{} & \mathrm{Map}(G^0,\mathbb{R}) & \ra{\partial^0} & \mathrm{Map}(G^1,\mathbb{R}) & \ra{\partial^1} & \mathrm{Map}(G^2,\mathbb{R}) & \ra{\partial^2} &...
\end{array}
$$
where \begin{equation}\begin{split}
\partial^n f(g_0,...,g_n)=\
&g_0f(g_1,...,g_n)+(-1)^{n+1}f(g_0,...,g_{n-1})\\
&-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{j+1} f(g_0,...,g_jg_{j+1},...,g_n).
\end{split}\end{equation}

**Added:** I know a proof that conjugation acts trivially on cohomology using syzygys, dimension shifting. But then I do not know why this is the same action as the one given on the bar complexes. Also I thought there might be an easier way?

Comment: You want to show conjugation acts trivially on cohomology. Can you do that?

Comment: I know a proof that conjugation acts trivially on cohomology using syzygys, dimension shifting. But then I do not know why this is the same action as the one given on the bar complexes. Also I thought there might be an easier way?

Comment: I've added the comment you (apparently) posted as an answer.  One reason to regain control of the Question itself, by account merger, is so that you can address the serious math formatting problems present in the posted version.

Comment: Anton, to reiterate the advice given to you by hardmath under the now deleted "answer". Read [the help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: I followed your advice and merged the accounts, thank you a lot. If you could tell me what exactly the serious math formatting problems are, I will get to them right away.